# Keep a track of filters in DC js aggregated data tables used for drill down using clickable rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

I have created an aggregated data table that filters other tables using clickable rows. Tried to create a drill down capability using DC.js aggregated tables and was able to put together a solution that works, thanks to Gordon's solution here on stack overflow. However,currently I am not able to figure out how I can keep a track of all the clicked row keys across tables, so that the user can undo any filters that were already selected.

Code for the aggregated data table that has row click filtering enabled.

```
//Fake Dimension
rank = function (p) { return "" };

var filterKeys = [];

//Remove any table row that has 0 or a garbage value
function checkRows(d){
    if(d.value.total<=0 || isNaN(d.value.total)||isNaN(d.value.average) ||d.value.average<=0 ||isNaN(d.value.count)||d.value.count<=0 ){
      return 0;
    }
    return d;
  }

//MarketTable
marketTable.width(500)
    .height(480)
    .dimension(AECMarketsGroup)
    .group(rank)
    .columns([function (d) { d=checkRows(d);
                            while(d!=0){
                              return d.key;
                             }
                           },
              function (d) { d=checkRows(d);
                            while(d!=0){
                              return                  
                          formatter(d.value.total);
                            } 
                           },
              function (d) { 
                d=checkRows(d);
                while(d!=0){
                  return formatter(d.value.count);
                }
              },
              function (d) {
                d=checkRows(d);
                while(d!=0){
                  return d.value.average;
                } 
              }])
    .sortBy(function (d) { return d.value.total })
    .order(d3.descending)

  //Enable click filtering
  marketTable.on('pretransition', function (table) {
    table.selectAll('td.dc-table-column')
      .on('click',function(d){           
      if(filterKeys.indexOf(d.key)===-1)
        filterKeys.push(d.key);
      else
        filterKeys = filterKeys.filter(k => k != d.key);
      if(filterKeys.length === 0)
        marketDim.filter(null);
      else 
        marketDim.filterFunction(function(d) {
          return filterKeys.indexOf(d) !== -1;
        })
      dc.redrawAll();
    })
  });
```

Here is the js fiddle with all 3 tables : https://jsfiddle.net/yashnigam/kvt9xnbs/21/

For example, if a user clicks on Europe in the first table, Amazon in the second table and Electronics in the third, I want to show a breadcrumb of the path the user has taken in the drill down, in this case Europe>>Amazon>>Electronics and be able to disable any of the applied filters, say I disable amazon, then the filter selection should be Europe>>Electronics

Another thing that I am facing trouble with is that the "reset all" button that I have implemented using dc.filterAll;dc.renderAll; does not reset the data after I make selections across tables.

```
      <h6 class="dc-data-count" style="float: left;margin-left:5px;">                     
                    <span>
                        <span class="filter-count"></span>
                         selected out of 
                        <span class="total-count"></span>
                         records |  
                       <a  id="reset" 
         href="javascript:dc.filterAll();dc.renderAll();"> Reset All</a>
                   </span>

        </h6>
```

It would be of great help if you can help me with any of the two problems I am facing 
1. Keeping a track of filters and being able to disable them 
2. Reset all data after filtering using rows in the tables or a reset option for individual tables.

Please help. Thanks!

Comment: Commenting this because there's probably a better way to do this but I'm not familiar with dc.js, but here you go: https://jsfiddle.net/1up8a9zx/. I basically defined a 'breadcrumb' variable that stores the names of the country/vendor/category that are clicked and displays it at the top of the file, next to the 'Fictisious company data' and 'Reset All' button. Lines 1-5, 132, 134, 186, 188, 237, 239, and 257-269 show what I've changed.

Comment: IMO a breadcrumb implies a hierarchy, but in this case the dimensions are independent - the user could just as well select from bottom to top as from top to bottom. Also, I'm not clear if you intend to select only one item per dimension, or to allow multiple selection - the code you are using allows multiple selection (very much like the ordinal bar chart or the row chart).

Comment: Thanks REEE and Gordon. I mentioned breadcrumb but what I really need is to be able to 1)reset individual tables and 2)reset the entire dashboard(doesn't currently work heres the jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/yashnigam/kvt9xnbs/48/ ). The group that I used to create the aggregated table is a custom reduce grp. I tried using <tableDimension>.filter(null) but it did not help me reset an individual table and dc.filterAll; dc.renderAll does not reset all data. I intend to allow multiple selection by dim and maintain a dynamic list of filter keys to show all filters and to be disabled onclick

Comment: @YashNigam Here: https://jsfiddle.net/kvt9xnbs/55/, look at the last part of the js code.

Comment: This is very helpful @REEE and it works as required.  Please post your solution below and I will accept it as the answer. Just want to check if you have an idea about undoing a filter based on a key. For example dimension.filter(null) resets all filters on the current dimension, but what if I need to reset just the current filter, say, I have clicked on Walmart, Amazon and Costco but need to undo just amazon's filter i.e. dimension.filter('amazon')  by clicking on a link that is shown only when a filter exists on the key. Regardless of this, I will accept your answer. Thanks a lot.